# Trying to get different version of jQuery to work

Tags: jquery, plugins

Hi there guys what I'm trying to do is have a clock jQuery plugin and a weather plugin but it's different versions I've tried the following

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var $i = jQuery.noConflict();
    alert($i.fn.jquery);
</script> 

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script>
    var $i = jQuery.noConflict();
    alert($i.fn.jquery);
</script> 
<script src="jquery.simpleWeather.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

It won't work for some reason, as in the plugin won't even appear on the page either of them. If I remove one of them they will work. Any ideas? Cheers

Comment: I don't think you should use the same variable for the two different jQuery versions. Try `$i` and `$j` or something similar.